# Can someone provide a minimal working example of ansible role dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, ansible

I am trying to use Ansible's dependencies feature but I cannot get it to work. Could someone provide a minimal example of a role that depends on another role that uses the dependencies feature eg:

`---
dependencies:
  - { role: common }`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use it if you put the content you specified in your question in this file:

```
<your-project-home>/roles/webservers/meta/main.yml
```

Make sure your `common` role exists in:

```
<your-project-home>/roles/common
```

Make sure your project structure looks like this:

```
yourplaybook.yml
roles/
   common/
   webservers/
```

`yourplaybook.yml` should look something like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
     - webservers
```

Then you would call your playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./inventory-file yourplaybook.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried a bunch of things. I have been invoking a role by typing `ansible-playbook <project_root>/roles/web-servers/tasks/main.yml`. The dependency is specified in `<project_root>/roles/web-servers/meta/main.yml` and the common role is in `<project_root>/roles/common/tasks/main.yml`.

Do I have to explicitly set `<your-ansible-home>`?

Comment: The way you are calling it you are basically making your role your playbook so it can't find your `common` role. Check my edit, you should call the playbook not the role when you run `ansible-playbook`